# Web3JS API confusing?

Tags: web3js

**TL,DR: Is anyone also experiencing problems with the [Web3JS documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#eth-contract)?**

I am very confused by the API documentation of Web3Js because of its behaviour.

(1)

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

Error: VM4943:1 Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a function at :1:10

But when I use...

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.contract(abi, address);    // Minor c
```

**it is working just fine**.

---

(2)

```
var contract2 = contract1.clone();
```

Error: VM5261:1 Uncaught TypeError: contract3.clone is not a function
    at :1:11

---

(3)

My aim is to create a default contract (already done), clone/copy it. But I am stuck where it comes to receiving the contractAddress from the newly created contract:

```
var SampleContract = eth.contract(abi);

var contractInstance = new SampleContract.new(30, {data: byteCode, from: firstAccount, gas: estimate, gasPrice: estimate});

...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the documentation of [version 1.x](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract), but you're using [version 0.x](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)
I am using 1.2.7 (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.2.7/dist/web3.min.js) and also reading it...

Comment: @Hashtag3232: No you're not! The syntax `web3.eth.contract` (with a lower-case `c`) is of v0.x. Note that you may have web3.js v1.x installed in one place and web3.js v0.x installed in another place, which is where your script imports it from. For example, if you're using Truffle v4.x or lower, then it internally relies on web3.js v0.x. So in all of your Truffle tests, web3.js v0.x will be automatically (and implicitly) imported.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Wordpress it was somehow already an old version installed (0.2.0) -> var version = web3.version.api;